# Is root-n consistency of $\hat \eta_n$ equivalent with saying $n^{1/2}(\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0)$ bounded in probability?

Tags: probability

I'm reading Semiparametric theory by Tsiatis, in Section 3.3 page 39, there is a statement

> Assume that we can find a root-n consistent estimator for the nuisance parameter $\hat{\eta}_n$ (i.e., where $n^{1/2}(\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0)$ is bounded in probability).

The statement is unclear to me, therefore, I want to show an estimator is root-n consistent is equivalent with saying this estimator is bounded in probability.

If I understand the basic concept correct, $n^{1/2}(\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0)$ is bounded in probability means that $n^{1/2}(\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0) = O_p(1)$.

However, I'm not sure what does it mean by saying $\hat\eta_n$ is a root-n consistent estimator. Does it mean $n^{1/2}(\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0) = o_p(1)$? I don't think so because then it implies that $o_p(1)$ and $O_p(1)$ are equivalent, which is not true. To that end, it seems like $\hat{\eta}_n −\eta_0 = o_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ is also incorrect, because it is just a rewrite of the previous one.

Therefore, may I double check what is the mathematical expression for root-n consistent estimator?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought here is my answer.

The author's root-n consistency is basically defined with $n^{1/2}(\hat\eta_n-\eta_0) = O_p(1)$.

Another way to write it is $(\hat\eta_n-\eta_0)=\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}
O_p(1)$.

Since $\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} = o(1)$, $\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}=o_p(1)$. Moreover, by the fact that $o_p(1)O_p(1) = o_p(1)$, we have $$\hat\eta_n-\eta_0 = o_p(1),$$ which is saying that the estimator $\hat\eta_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\eta_0$.

By stating root-n consistency instead of merely consistency, the author is emphasizing the rate. By just saying $\hat\eta_n$ is $o_p(1)$, we basically "lose" the opportunity to show more information of $\hat \eta_n$.